# How can I recursively match a pattern using Regular Expressions?

Tags: java, regex

The string can be like one of the following:

```
a(b,c)
a(a(b,c),d)
a(a(a(a(a(b,c),d),a(e,f)),g),h)
etc
```

I want to match an unlimited number of "a(x,y)". How can I do that using Regex? Here's what I have:

```
\\w\\(((?:\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\))|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)),((?:\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\))|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+))\\)
```

It only matches up two recursions of "a(x,y)".

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187704/363573

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java's standard regex lib does not support recursion, so you can't match such general nested constructs with it.

But in flavors that do support recursion (Perl, PCRE, .NET, etc) you can use expressions like:

```
\w+(?:\((?R)(?:,(?R))*\))?
```

Comment: Are you sure Python has such a feature? AFAIK, only PHP, .NET and Perl are capable of such trickery.

Comment: @BartKiers, correct, Python does not have `(?R)` and friends, for some reason I thought that newer versions of its regex engine did support it. Removed it from the list.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Python, so I thought they included it in v3 (which I haven't really looked at).

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Ruby.  Since version 1.9 it has used the Oniguruma regex library, which does support recursion.

Comment: @AlanMoore, Oniguruma was the one I was thinking about, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I know that PCRE can do it. @Qtax is there a reference to your claim that java.util.regex (respectively scala.util.matching.Regex) does not have recursive regex support?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use my Regular Expression library https://github.com/florianingerl/com.florianingerl.util.regex , that supports Recursive Regular Expressions! The API is basically the same as the one of java.util.regex, just the required import statements are different, e.g.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<first>a\\((?<second>(?'first')|[a-zA-Z]),(?'second')\\))");
assert p.matcher("a(a(a(a(a(b,c),d),a(e,f)),g),h)").find();
```

Comment: doesr not suppor ?R

Answer (score 0):

2 options -
1) Use Lexical Analysis to do the pattern matching & replacement on your own [OR]
2) If you want to stick to Regex then use some shell programming (or any supporting language) & call it from Java.

Answer (score -3):

The language you're describing isn't a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) so it can't be matched by a regular expression. Look into [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (i.e. use a parser)

Comment: -1. Regex (in this context) are not regular, and they haven't been for 25+ years now.

Comment: Nitpick: lexical analysis is based on regular expressions; lexical analysis turns a stream of characters into a stream of symbols according to rules defined by regular expressions.  The thing that solves the problem that the asker asks about is parser generators.

Comment: @robert, (obviously?) Qtax meant regex in OS-tools/programming API's. Regex in that context have had the capability to match something that had been matched before (grouping and back-referencing): making them able to match more than regular languages.

Comment: The point is, simply saying "that's not a regular language" doesn't help.  We're talking about *regexes*, not theory-pure regular expressions.  Some regex flavors support recursion, but Java doesn't happen to be one of them.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are looking for something like:

a(x,y) = [a-z] ( [a-z] , [a-z] )

regex = a(x,y) | a(regex|y) | a(x, regex)

Not sure how you can do in a language.