# How to get data from nested parentheses?

Tags: java, arrays, string, nested, parentheses

I have the next String with nested parentheses:

```
String a = "(red(blue))grey((orange)green)";
```

And I want to fill an array with the value of each parentheses that prints out:

```
(red(blue))
(blue)
grey
((orange)green)
(orange)
//In any order
```

Comment: I will give a approach here , you can use stack to each of character will be insert into it.lets say (..) -> named as a container each container contains container so on.if u encounter with ( insert into stack go on until encounter to ')' character when you encounter with  ) character pop until '(' and create container object insert into stack and also list to show this will work on your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recursively match a pattern using Regular Expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659764/how-can-i-recursively-match-a-pattern-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: Salvador, you should show what you have tried, so that we can see that you have actually tried things

Answer (score 0):

I Think Below code should work:

Algorithm :  First mark the end position of opening parenthesis using a stack and then next iteration you have the opening position and closing position.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "(red(blue))grey((orange)green)";
        int n = s.length();
        int end[] = new int[n];
        boolean internalWords = false;
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='('){
                stack.push(i);
            }else if(s.charAt(i)==')'){
                int start = (Integer)stack.pop();
                end[start] = i;
            }else if(stack.isEmpty()){
                System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)=='('){

                for(int j = i ; j <= end[i]; j++){
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

out put :
 `grey
(red(blue))
(blue)
((orange)green)
(orange)`